# Dynamic Json Payload

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

```
               <tem:CountryName></tem:CountryName>(yes/no)
               <tem:Bangladesh></tem:Bangladesh>(1/0)
               <tem:Bhutan></tem:Bhutan>(1/0)
```

if `CountryName` is `yes` and if `bangladesh` or `bhutan` is 1 then below payload should build,

```
{
                    "name": "Extension Country Name",
                    "value": "yes"
 },
{
                    "name": "Extension Country Name",
                    "value": "Bangladesh"
 },
{
                    "name": "Extension Country Name",
                    "value": "Bhutan"
   }
```

How can I implement this wso2 EI, please suggest.

I tried using filter mediator not working because there multiple country names up to 7.